# Нужен пример реализации многоуровневой архитектуры в asp net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Хотелось бы найти пример реализализации в проекте asp.net CORE mvc многоуровневой архитектуры. Видел один видеокурс, но он мне очень не зашел. В любом случае хотелось бы больше информации, но гугл ничего нового уже не подсказывает.

Под многоуровневой архитектурой подразумеваю деление всего приложение на слои:

**DataLayer** - как я понял здесь обычные модели для Entity Framework.

**BuisnessLayer** - Взаимодействует с PresentationLayer  и DataLayer. В данный уровень пихают якобы функционал типа CRUD-a делая некие классы а-ля xxxRepository, которые реализуют интерфейсы IxxxRepository.

**PresentationLayer**  - такая херня! Практически копирует DataLayer модели причем мне непонятным образом(по крайней мере тот пример что я видел очень непонятен) в свои модели, эти модели ты можешь как угодно дополнять добавляя поля в модель, далее создаются к этим моделям "сервисы" представляющие собой крайне неугодную мне дич. А именно каждый сервис для модели представляет  кучку неких кастомных методов. Типичный метод представляет аля поиск, например, в бд по айди. При чем эти методы используют методы из BuisnessLayer.